# Why can't I find the file with normalized path on windows system?

Tags: java, file-io, path

I want to check if a file exists by its filepath using java. I know there is a method in Paths class called normalized(). Here is my code:

```
File file = Paths.get(fileName).normalize().toFile();
        if (!file.exists()) {
            return "File does not exist.";
        }
```

The filename is a file path with sysmbols of current directory like "."or".."
After the path is normalized, it just delete the dots of the path and windows can't find the new path with out dots. But the code above works fine on other systems. I wonder why and what should I do if I want to check if a path with dots exists or not?

Answer (score 0):

Why are switching from the Paths API to the file API?

use: `Files.exists(Paths.get(fileName).normalize());`

As the docs says, normalize removes /./ constructs, as well as X/../ constructs. This can nevertheless result in slightly different intended files in case of weird softlink constructions, which, yes, even on windows, is a thing you can do. It may be related to that. Give us the path pre- and post normalization (just sysout it) and we can perhaps give you some more details on this.

Generally you don't want normalize. Depending on situation you either just want the path as is, or, (in case you need to store it for later, check it against certain filters, or render it to the user), `path.toAbsolutePath()`.